# Saving a dictionary of dataframes as separate .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a series of large data frames. The number will change depending on the inputs of the code. Each dataframe will then have a again a varying number of rows and columns. The number of columns is the same for each of the dataframes in a dictionary but the number of rows will vary between dataframes. Here is a single dataframe from my dictionary:

```
{'093nb-a':                 1    2    3    4    5             6             7             8             9        10  ...           31           32           33           34            35            36            37            38            39            40
product                                                                                                  ...                                                                                                                                        
043-096(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.928800e-02  2.221950e-01  2.104710  ...    10.684400     8.809840     7.921030     6.975370  6.472240e+00  5.643140e+00  5.340900e+00  5.088400e+00  4.468070e+00  4.092830e+00
041-092(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...    27.343100    26.348200    27.005100    25.692700  2.433850e+01  2.312400e+01  2.292020e+01  2.166400e+01  2.062450e+01  1.961710e+01
043-093(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000  0.000000e+00  2.019000e-01  1.145850e+00  6.568850e+00  1.580680e+01  2.964780e+01
041-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.001590  ...    54.059900    49.499700    45.770400    43.115200  4.162900e+01  3.929880e+01  3.760480e+01  3.625430e+01  3.542060e+01  3.510910e+01
041-093(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000272  ...     9.123110     8.516590     7.405670     6.951680  6.639450e+00  6.371910e+00  5.821850e+00  5.535770e+00  5.392260e+00  5.291000e+00
043-096(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  8.488600e-03  1.094350e-01  0.975641  ...     2.517700     2.374990     2.345830     2.002980  1.865650e+00  1.750060e+00  1.715700e+00  1.681990e+00  1.358840e+00  1.296470e+00
042-093(L16)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.012354     0.035613     0.065930     0.100664  1.729990e-01  1.172700e+00  1.178630e+01  3.434970e+01  7.109020e+01  1.136440e+02
043-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000  7.288420e-01  8.628490e+00  3.177190e+01  7.529960e+01  1.314360e+02  1.981620e+02
041-095(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.004043     0.005084     0.006025     0.007093  7.659520e-03  8.165380e-03  8.903470e-03  8.237130e-03  8.687170e-03  9.185370e-03
042-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.308164     0.535273     0.776155     1.971320  6.158180e+00  1.346020e+01  2.028300e+01  2.922050e+01  3.994700e+01  5.241390e+01
043-095(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...   512.543000   412.627000   317.795000   233.591000  1.838820e+02  1.453260e+02  1.051780e+02  7.979190e+01  6.791930e+01  5.806560e+01
043-094(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...    21.799500    24.550900    26.159300    25.745400  2.536940e+01  2.359510e+01  2.092200e+01  1.799270e+01  1.547530e+01  1.292230e+01
041-092(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...    64.925000    66.531400    66.476800    64.894800  6.148120e+01  5.922860e+01  5.580080e+01  5.150720e+01  4.853910e+01  4.493510e+01
041-095(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.069713     0.092968     0.114729     0.138480  1.453310e-01  1.530490e-01  1.583970e-01  1.407330e-01  1.371880e-01  1.355580e-01
041-091(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...    30.032300    40.332400    44.996500    47.000700  5.271180e+01  5.372560e+01  5.788070e+01  6.146730e+01  6.655750e+01  7.144250e+01
041-090(L02)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  5.594050e-05  8.369660e-04  2.903470e-03  1.917730e-02
041-090(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.534300e-03  8.703700e-03  4.770440e-02  1.738080e-01
041-094(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.532802     0.720289     0.929777     1.033430  1.254450e+00  1.385020e+00  1.635600e+00  1.817290e+00  2.056140e+00  2.293480e+00
043-094(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...   519.805000   620.513000   724.166000   820.729000  8.732280e+02  9.074630e+02  9.164940e+02  8.776860e+02  7.838060e+02  6.768200e+02
041-091(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     6.299650    10.849700    12.339300    14.101300  1.685690e+01  1.810710e+01  2.097550e+01  2.283200e+01  2.553310e+01  2.845680e+01
039-089(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.021291     0.028549     0.037696     0.051105  6.335970e-02  7.822260e-02  9.664860e-02  1.074630e-01  1.214690e-01  1.348120e-01
043-097(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2.299380e-12  2.137050e-07  1.618280e-08  4.806170e-08  0.000215  ...     0.000004     0.000003     0.000003     0.000002  4.996970e-07  1.754870e-07  7.402690e-08  5.900700e-08  1.725820e-08  1.416280e-08
041-094(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.224109     0.329906     0.465128     0.574359  7.598240e-01  9.471510e-01  1.195480e+00  1.458680e+00  1.727560e+00  2.054990e+00
039-089(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.010328     0.013777     0.013199     0.015000  1.716070e-02  1.983690e-02  2.039220e-02  2.140960e-02  2.252160e-02  2.330300e-02
043-095(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...    13.308400    11.084000     9.514860     8.730070  7.958640e+00  7.249500e+00  6.697730e+00  6.278970e+00  6.019280e+00  5.670850e+00
043-097(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.379290e-07  5.388180e-06  1.827400e-07  8.016440e-07  0.005352  ...     0.000394     0.000228     0.000131     0.000087  4.040010e-05  6.121160e-06  1.084730e-06  6.949800e-07  1.232050e-07  1.013090e-07
sum           0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.379313e-07  5.601885e-06  2.777680e-02  3.316308e-01  3.085918  ...  1080.658398  1079.959961  1087.902154  1097.773909  1.099505e+03  1.099857e+03  1.089266e+03  1.070388e+03  1.026290e+03  9.866779e+02
over          NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000  ...     0.012315     0.010263     0.008746     0.007953  7.238386e-03  6.591310e-03  6.148847e-03  5.866067e-03  5.865089e-03  5.747418e-03
```

I have checked the type of items in the dataframe using `print(type(dict))` and got `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

I have tried to save to csv using:

```
for i in df_dict: 
   df_dict[i].to_csv[i]
```

This returns an error of:

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '093nb-a'
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a file name as a string to the `to_csv` function, not just a number. Try doing this:

```
for i in df_dict: 
   df_dict[i].to_csv('dataframe_id_'+str(i)+'.csv')
```